# How to fix Cannot resolve method 'openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The error keeps coming even if I remove the context or add it

```
public class fileHelper {
    public static final String FILENAME = "listinfo.dat";
    public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> items, View.OnClickListener context){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(items);
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have already tried removing the context

Comment: @a_local_nobody not really a duplicate, the issue of the other question is distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View.OnClickListener is not a context (and not the one you need). You need to use the Context from your calling activity

```
   public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> items, Context context){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(items);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: then it is giving this error
Non-static method 'openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Provide the context then... no fun helping by getting downvoted... just think about using the correct context in your writeData Method

Comment: the intent HAS a context!

Comment: the activity is a context. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity you got me. Nevertheless, will you need the context of the caller, to get to the function

Comment: Now, that is reasonable.  But next time do the research first, rather than start by posting a series of wildly wrong guesses

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> items, View.OnClickListener context)
```

Although you define an argument *called* "context". it is not an Android `Context`.

A `Context` is an object such as an instance of an `Activity` or an `Application` so you will need to pass one of those (an instance, not a reference to the class itself) to the code which needs to use this.

In crude terms, an *instance* of an `Activity` or `Application` would be the "this" of code inside an appropriate method of such a class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't passing a context into the method.

```
View.OnClickListener context
```

That isn't the context. It's the `onClickListener`.

You need to pass in the `Context` and then use it like so:

```
public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> items, Context context){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(items);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```